# How to sort import statements in Eclipse in case insensitive order?

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse sorts import statements within the import groups using lexicographical order, which is case sensitive.

For example :

```
import com.company.something.DBException;
import com.company.something.DatabaseHandler;
```

Is it possible to change that automatic sorting to be case insensitive. In the above example, I'd like the order to be :

```
import com.company.something.DatabaseHandler;
import com.company.something.DBException;
```

Comment: You could write an eclipse plugin

Comment: @KarlM I was hoping for a simpler solution. Currently I'm fixing such mis-ordered imports manually, and there aren't many of them. Considering that's I've never wrote an Eclipse plugin, I'm assuming learning how to do it would require time that I don't have.

Comment: As far as I can see the sort always uses the default collator for the current locale.

Answer (score 6):

I found a way to do it: first, there in the `Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Organize Imports` option, delete all the entries that indicate specific packages order:

[image: Delete custom package entries]

And then enter one single entry with only a `*` character.

[image: Add * single entry]

Apparently, this indicates you don't want to specify any custom order and then Eclipse decides the order method, which by default seems to be lexicographical.

That's it. Next time you execute the `Source > Organize Imports` command or the `CTRL + SIFT + O` shortcut, the order will be lexicographical.

Answer (score 2):

The import organisation behaviour in Eclipse can be controlled in `Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Organize Imports`. Unfortunately, there does not appear to be a way of changing the order the way you like.

Comment: In that case, it doesn't answer my question, but thanks for trying.

Comment: Yes it does.  Your question was "is it possible", and the answer appears to be "no".

Comment: @DavidWallace To my understanding "there does not appear to be a way" means that the person who answered can't think of a way to do it, or thinks there's no way to do it. That doesn't mean the answer is no (unless the person who answered developed that feature in Eclipse).

Comment: Hi, I found the way to do it. The answer is actually there in the "Organize Imports" option. Look at my post below.

Answer (score 1):

The [AnyEdit](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/anyedit-tools) Eclipse plugin adds various editing tools to the context menu - including case-insensitive sorting of lines of text. Select your imports, right click, choose Sort, case-insensitive.

Not sure how you would automate it, but it's got to be better than manual.

> "Current version works with Eclipse from 3.8 to 4.6 and requires Java
>   = 1.7, but older AnyEdit versions for Eclipse 2.1 up to 3.7 may be downloaded from the homepage too."

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try.